# PySpark - create new key

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have rdd with list like

```
{
    "name": "adam",
    "gender": "male",
    "new_column": "white,black,yellow"
}
```

How to create new rdd with key value like:

```
{
    "name": "adam",
    "gender": "male",
    "new_column": "white"
}
{
    "name": "adam",
    "gender": "male",
    "new_column": "black"
}
{
    "name": "adam",
    "gender": "male",
    "new_column": "yellow"
}
```

Can someone guide me in the right direction.

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- new_column: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Spark 1.5, you can use `split` and then `explode` functions as follow:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("new_column", F.explode(F.split("new_column", ",")))
```

You can find all functions you can use in pyspark in [pyspark functions documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql.html#functions)

Comment: Thanks you mate it work as expected one small problem is pyspark won't save data

Comment: >>> df.count()
412
>>> df2.count()
554
df2.write.format('json').save('final')

Comment: What do you mean by "pyspark won't save data" ? Because `df2.write.format('json').save('final')` is the right way to write a dataframe to `final` directory. Do you have any error ? Everything works without error but you're not able to find where pyspark wrote data ?